# Connection between SDE and Fokker-Planck

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

First of all, I would like to know if my intuitive understanding is correct.

This should be, in a sense, the same as what one does when passing from the Lagrangian point of view to the Eulerian point of view in analysis/fluid dynamics: namely, if you for example have a continuity equation you can relate the evolution of the density with the trajectories of the particles. In the stochastic case however you have a randomness in the SDE describing the Lagrangian dynamics (this is called also Langevin dynamics in the stochastic case if I am not mistaken) that translates in a diffusive term for the Fokker-Planck equation, where the role of the density is played by the pdf.

Now, what I was wondering is what is the connection between the coefficient of the Brownian motion $\sigma$ in the SDE

$$ d X_t = b(t, X_t) dt + \sigma dW_t$$

and the viscosity $\nu$ in

$$ \partial_t \rho = - \mathrm{div}(b \rho) + \nu \Delta \rho.$$

Comment: $\nu=\sigma^2/2$. You can see it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation#One_dimension).